# How to load nested components from single xhr call in flux.

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, flux

I have to render jsx components dynamically like this:

```
<document>
    <page>
        <frame>
            <image>
            </image>
        </frame>
     </page>
</document>
```

from data like:

```
{
"document": {

   "other properties" : ...
   "page": {

      "other properties" : ...
      "frame": {

         "other properties" : ...
         "image": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which(whole document) comes from single service call now my every component like document, frame, page, image have respective stores like document store, page store etc.
When i receive data from api i call action to update document store but cant figure out how to update other nested component stores.

If i use props to send data to nested child component i think i am violating

> source of truth

and that is why want to update store with data and then use store to set state of my component.

But if i try to update page store through action in document store and then update frame store from page store react will give me error "cannot dispatch in middle of dispatch".
I believe i am missing a core point but what is it.

Comment: Usually if I'm working with an upfront data load, meaning I'm getting data once on load and never again, I'll do that data load then populate my store then render my components. Now if I'm making multiple data calls dependent on user iteration I'll use sources and have my store contain my state that the components use. Then use actions to modify the store and my components will update when the store values change.

Comment: Are you suggesting that on response of apiutils i should populate all stores at one place?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which tools you're using. Its up to you to decide if an upfront load works for the amount of data you have or if you only want to load the data only when its absolutely needed. I have a tool right now I'm building that loads 2 json files upfront that are 150kb combined. It was easier and more intuitive code wise to load them immediately. If you think about it, that's probably less kb than most images on your page. However, if you're constantly calling a back-end, that solution won't work.

Comment: All stores listen to all events so you can use same event from your action to trigger multiple store updates. It will be done with single dispatch so you won't get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if i try to update page store through action in document store and then update frame store from page store react will give me error "cannot dispatch in middle of dispatch".

You are indeed missing a core point.

The purpose of flux is to have a one-direction flow of data.  Each piece of the flux flow should only receive information from one other location.

So your stores should **only** receive information from the Dispatcher and should **only** send data to the components.  You are trying to either cross-talk your stores, or have your stores send information to the Dispatcher.  Neither of these are accepted.

Instead, simply have both your Page Store and your Frame Store listen for the same dispatch and each respond in their own way, if you want them both to consume this data.

That said, I wouldn't solve this problem that way.

> If i use props to send data to nested child component i think i am violating source of truth

Nope!

In an ideal flux flow, only one component should talk to the stores.  This component is called the "container", and sits as the top-level parent for your entire application.  It then **becomes** the source of truth for all of it's children, passing information down to them via props.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html#best-practices) is a description of such from the Flux docs.

Comment: Thanks I understand your first part of answer know. But for second part If container like in this case "document container" pass all data as props to page then frame then image. And after that image store value changes.Only "document container" component should listen to image store change? 
or I can let child component have there own container components which listens to respective stores and update there contained view with props.

Comment: Ideally, yes, only containers should connect to stores. You can choose to use multiple containers, but keep in mind that the design philosophy of containers says that they should not receive any props from their parents.  So only use containers at junctions where the sub components are logically distinct from their parent.